# Convert a column in R data frame to lower case

Tags: r

Here is my data

```
summary(RecordsWithIssues)
ID             OTHERSTATE        OTHERCOUNTRY      
Length:373         Length:373         Length:373        
Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character

> head(RecordsWithIssues)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
                  ID OTHERSTATE      OTHERCOUNTRY
               <chr>      <chr>             <chr>
1 0034000001uhro2AAA         MO              <NA>
2 0034000001uhyOsAAI       <NA>          reseller
3 0034000001uhyPJAAY       <NA>          AECbytes
4 0034000001uhyPZAAY       <NA>            Friend
5 0034000001uhyPeAAI       <NA>            client
6 0034000001uhyPnAAI       <NA>     good energies
```

I do the following

```
RecordsWithIssues[,3]=tolower(RecordsWithIssues[,3])
RecordsWithIssues[1,3]
# A tibble: 1 × 1
                                                                                                             OTHERCOUNTRY
                                                                                                                    <chr>
1 c(na, "reseller", "aecbytes", "friend", "client", "good energies", "boss", "friend", "linkedin", "aecbytes", "
>
```

As you can see data frame now has a vector instead of single text value. How can I simply convert the string without getting the text

Comment: Be aware of the ojects that you are working with. This is not a data.frame. It is one of the hadleyverse objects. They sometimes have rules that don't follow those of the base R objects.

Comment: OK, I was unaware of these object types! Is there a way to convert these to base R objects?

Comment: Most likely `mydf <- as.data.frame(mydf)` will work to strip the extra structure off. (or `as.matrix`, etc where appropriate).

Answer (score 19):

We need to extract with `[[` as the dataset also include the `tbl_df` class

```
RecordsWithIssues[[3]] <- tolower(RecordsWithIssues[[3]])
```

Or `$`

```
RecordsWithIssues$OTHERCOUNTRY <- tolower(RecordsWithIssues$OTHERCOUNTRY)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
require(tidyverse)

RecordsWithIssues %>% mutate(OTHERCOUNTRY = tolower(OTHERCOUNTRY))
```

Answer (score 1):

The [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) way:

```r
require(data.table)

setDT(RecordsWithIssues)
RecordsWithIssues[ , OTHERCOUNTRY := tolower(OTHERCOUNTRY) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my data

[image]

## To convert to lower

```
head(rounds2)

rounds2_lower <-data.frame(tolower(rounds2$company_permalink))
```

## cbind- to bind both the dataframes to a final data frame

```
rounds2_final <- cbind(rounds2,rounds2_lower)
```

## give appropriate names to the column

```
> names(rounds2_final)
[1] "company_permalink"       "funding_round_permalink"     
[3] ""tolower.rounds2.company_permalink."

names(rounds2_final)[3] <- "company_permalink_lower"
```